# AdBlock on Android causes many timeouts and connection problems

Tags: connection-issues, data-connection, processes, adblock-plus

When I use the Android version of Adblock Plus 1.3 without root, everything seems to work fine. But now, I have a new phone that I'm not willing to root, and I like the idea of having AdBlock as a proxy to strip everything, but everything times out quite often. Sometimes it works, but others it just keeps timing out and creating all kinds of connection problems.

I updated recently to the latest dev version [from here](https://downloads.adblockplus.org/devbuilds/adblockplusandroid/), but I still have the same problem.

I feel that this issue is happened because of power saving maybe? Some kind of deprioritization of AdBlock?

I have Galaxy Note 8.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on Reddit suggested an awesome solution. The solution is a program called DNS66. It's available on the F-droid store for free. It creates a local VPN server that blocks all ads. I love it, and I'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question answers itself. The app you're using is run by a proxy server and it may slow down your webpage load time. I suggest you to block ad servers from hosts file and use the regular browser app as it's the fastest and most practical way of getting rid of ads.

Comment: I can't use root. I fixed the question. I found another solution anyway.